# Console.ReadLine() not working in VS Code, writing a code in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am learning C# and I am using VS Code, when I tried to take input from user using Console.ReadLine() it's not working.

I referred from a video which did exactly same thing and still after a couple of Google searches I couldn't figure out where I went wrong.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hi! {0}", name);
```

My main method has only this 3 lines and it always gives as output something like this:

[image]

Screencast: [image]

It never prints the last line of code

Comment: If your app is being closed, add Console.ReadLine() or ReadKey() for example at end of your console program, or run without debugger (ctrl + f5 visual studio, not sure about code..)

Comment: @Cid How is it related to the question? It doesn't matter what you use, VS Code, VS or event notepad++

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: I am running within VS Code itself, using (ctrl + F5) i.e. run without debugger

Answer (score 27):

This was happening because the default console in VS Code was external terminal. If you set it integrated terminal, it allows you to take input from user.

It can be done by setting **"console": "integratedTerminal"** in launch.json file.

Comment: You should accept this answer, that way others can immediately see your solution :)

Comment: I had the same issue with the FSharp console application in VS code.
The solution explained by Marx works fine for me.
I've also found this helpful documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0#set-up-for-terminal-input 
I just need to keep in mind it ends up having two VS Code tool windows to handle this case: 1) Terminal - where we can type the input and see the output; 2) Debug - where we can see only the debug-related stuff.

Answer (score 6):

it actually works, but it happens so fast you can not see it.

try adding `Console.ReadKey();`
this way the program will not stop until you press a random key on your keyboard.

Comment: No, it actually does *not* work: [see screencast](https://imgur.com/WcClC3X). The VS Code debug console is indeed behaving strange...

Comment: then i am almost 100% sure something goes wrong in his program and not with c# itself.

Answer (score 5):

Tutorial: Debug a .NET console application using Visual Studio Code

The Debug Console doesn't accept terminal input for a running program. To handle terminal input while debugging, you can use the integrated terminal (one of the Visual Studio Code windows) or an external terminal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a readline as follows

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hi! {0}", name);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will cause your program to pause at the end and you should see the output.

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you dont want to see it forever you can set a timer to freeze the display.

```c
using System.Threading;

Console.WriteLine("Enter your name : ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hi! {0}", name);
Thread.Sleep(5000) //In milliseconds - will display for 5 seconds
```