# Is There a Problem With My Code or is Visual Studio Code Broken

Tags: c#, for-loop, visual-studio-code

I am new to c#, but have been coding in java before. I downloaded visual studio code and the c# extension, and it seems to be working when I do `Console.WriteLine("Example");` yet when I have a for loop it seems to not run it. I have a really simple sum calculator, but it doesn't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    Console.Write("Started Program");
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Choose numbers you want to add: ");
        int num = Console.Read();
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and it does work on my machine, try reloading your IDE

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to run it"? And while your code seems to be syntactically correct on a first glance, you are probably misunderstanding the method `Console.Read()`, which reads the input from the console character-wise, ie if you input `A` it will return 65.

Comment: "it does not seem to run" is the programmer equivalent of the end-user' "everything is broken" - please specify what you expect, what is the current situation and what you were expecting.

Comment: @mjwills that's probably because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664418/console-readline-not-working-in-vs-code-writing-a-code-in-c-sharp... Let's assume that strange `Console.Read` usage is what OP wants (as their can read MSDN as well as all of us).

Comment: What I mean is it isn't even running the first print statement in the for loop

Comment: @MonteScottBarber - If I understand you correctly you're seeing "Started Program...", but not "Choose numbers you want to add: "? Then the code you've posted isn't the code you're running. Can you please confirm and update your code, if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Its probably passing the .read input as ASCII characters instead of the actual int ... try changing;

`int num = Console.Read();`

to

`int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`